# Is “family of [number]” inclusive?

Tags: meaning-in-context, idiomatic-language

In the sentence: ‘Mr. Thomson and his family of three came to my home.’ Is the ‘family of three’ part including Mr. Thomson himself or not?

Comment: It's an odd sentence because it should be inclusive, but the structure, specifically the word "and", supports an exclusive interpretation. For comparison, "Mr. and Mrs. Thompson's little family of three" is inclusive.

Comment: @Luke Sawczak, Thank you for your comment. Is it better to rewite my sentence as ‘Mr. Thomson’s family of three came to my house.’?

Comment: That's a good option.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I am not mistaken, the expression *his family of three* relates to the number of people in Mr Thomson's family (thus there are three people in his family: he, his wife and their only child), whereas **a mother of three** indicates the number of the mother's children.